# Replace typescript error "expression of type X can't be used to index type Y" with undefined

Tags: typescript

Consider the following code:

```
const myObject = {
  foo: 'val1',
  bar: 'val2'
} as const

type keys = keyof typeof myObject // 'foo' | 'bar'

const key: string = getKey() // returns some random string key

const result: 'val1' | 'val2' | undefined = myObject[key]
```

Typescript throws an error at `myObject[key]` with the message *Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type '{ readonly foo: "val1"; readonly bar: "val2"; }'.*
That's true, but I don't mind that - I'm fine with the expression evaluating to `undefined` if `key` is neither **foo** or **bar**.

I want typeof `result` to be `'val1' | 'val2' | undefined`, which is a perfectly valid - no assertions needed.

Is there any way to force TS into this?

Comment: TS doesn't have so-called "exact types" so it doesn't "know" that extra keys are definitely absent.  You'd have to simulate such behavior with a utility type/function.  Does [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/weypBw) work for you?  If so then I'll write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: @jcalz Yes, this is something like I was looking for. I wonder if stylistically this approach is better than using `isKeyOf` utility function as mentioned in the answer below. Definitely this is more succinct.

Comment: I don't think I can speak authoritatively about which approach is better "stylistically".  Fighting against the TypeScript type system isn't always worth the effort, so you might ultimately be happier avoiding the issue (by not indexing into an object with an unknown key) than trying to "force" TS into submission.  But since the question as asked is about such forcing, my approach is the way I'd do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TypeScript doesn't have direct support for so-called "exact types", as requested in [microsoft/TypeScript#12936](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/12936).  All object types in TypeScript are considered "open" or "extendible", so it's always possible for a value to have more properties than are known about in the type.  A value of type `{a: string}` is only known to possess a `string`-valued property at the key `"a"`.  It is *not* known to *lack* a property at, say, the key `"b"`.  Therefore the type of `{a: string}["b"]` is more akin to `unknown` (it could be anything at all) than to `undefined` (it is known not to exist).  Even object literals like

```
const o = { foo: 'val1', bar: 'val2' } as const;
/* const o: {
    readonly foo: "val1";
    readonly bar: "val2";
} */
```

have such technically extendible types:

```
const p = { foo: 'val1', bar: 'val2', baz: 'val3' } as const;
const q: typeof o = p; // okay
```

---

There isn't even a way to consistently express such a type in the type system.  The closest you can get is to give the type an [index signature](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#index-signatures) to describe the properties at arbitrary keys.  But you can't use index signatures to make exceptions for known keys.  That is, the following type is invalid:

```
interface Nope {
    readonly foo: "val1";
    readonly bar: "val2";
    readonly [rest: string]: undefined;
}
```

The index signature here means that **every** property with a `string` key will have an `undefined` value.  This conflicts with the `"foo"` and `"bar"` properties and the compiler complains.  There is a longstanding open feature request at [microsoft/TypeScript#17867](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/17867) to allow for a "rest" index signature that makes exceptions for known keys.  But for now it's not part of the language.

So the closest valid type you can write is

```
interface Yep {
    readonly foo: "val1";
    readonly bar: "val2";
    readonly [all: string]: "val1" | "val2" | undefined;
}
```

This might be good enough for your use case:

```
declare const key: string;
const myObject: Yep = { foo: 'val1', bar: 'val2' };
const r = myObject.foo; // const r: "val1"
const s = myObject[key]; // const s: "val1" | "val2" | undefined
const t = myObject.baz; // const t: "val1" | "val2" | undefined ‍♂️
```

---

If it *is* good enough, you can write a helper function to give an object literal such a type automatically:

```
const exactish = <const T,>(
    x: T & { [all: string]: T[keyof T] | undefined }
) => x
```

where the [intersection](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#intersection-types) gives combines the input type `T` with an index signature of the appropriate property type, and where I'm using a [`const` type parameter](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-5-0.html#const-type-parameters) to relieve the caller of the need to use a `const` assertion:

```
const myObject = exactish({
    foo: 'val1',
    bar: 'val2'
});
/* const myObject: {
     foo: "val1";
     bar: "val2";
   } & {
    [all: string]: "val1" | "val2" | undefined;
   }  */
```

That's an equivalent type to `Yep` above, and so it behaves the same for better or worse:

```
const r = myObject.foo; // const r: "val1"
const s = myObject[key]; // const s: "val1" | "val2" | undefined
const t = myObject.baz; // const t: "val1" | "val2" | undefined
```

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/FAYw9gdgzgLgBGOBeOBvOAzMYBccDkAbgIYA2AjPgDRwBGxATnkWQEz5wC+cxUc40GAG5gAegBU-SLAR5UwOIrgMApsQAmkUgE9M2PACISFAyKXK1miDrqNDx1qeDdxo0NPgAHZGj24CxpQ09EwBbNS2AF7MxgDMHNy8UoIiAjIAjngw2p4qYBgIPp5CcKKiCADWxNrAwACWEDAqDBjEICpwAHJguWgKSqoaWrpY-kZk5E7mg1Y2IfZsUwOWw3AA2qqweLAMDQDmALp4AK4Q6ioYDSrqIpy1DU0tbR0Amire8tMr1iP6cOMmMzLIY-WyhAGOIGKGarNZkUjbGC7CCHBYmOAAH3+DgMmLgp3Olwg11utXOIFIjA6aXgFRU2kRyL2qQ8cAAttoAPK0ABWKhAMDwb28KHQoxiEwi8zCpHYXBZgmUPg53L5AoAdKMSmVkjJwYEDO5FXwUCrefyYGs6doDtryjS4FA0ZM8RDcViCRcruojTJ4KaueaNfRInbdfBBdiJu6o7KY56idc4IA+DcA7LuAWAJAEJkgHg-2rACDENkqKCeZ5wACiAA82jA6lAABZ9cwOlTVgV1xsoAA8DoAKlQAHwACn65kUlbwvbgADJfHDSAjHUj9kc4L2rfT8muDniE96uKO4ABKZADuCV2rN1lmtX+uCtmsdoefMeKcUyoKH8zSliy-CHzgjyhUpJAdG8LTkL9zHfAFJmAsdpTdeDFG4WcX1fedFx2FdnRjN1dzOL1iRuKCuEUVxLyUB0oELFRexyFQhXeZVA1vMMAHcwAYCooEoxQHQYFjVQtTVsDDATcMPaihKDS1rVtUp7VZJ1YxdLF8I9QjEx9K9FTvcDg2IUNFPDOBI1gvCcQIwl9zTLNc2cIA)

Comment: Thanks, everything clicked for me when you mentioned that missing properties are more akin to `unknown` than `undefined`

Answer (score 1):

You could use a custom type guard with a [type predicate](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#using-type-predicates) to check if `key` is actually a key of `myObject`. That way you get around direct [`as`-assertions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-assertions) with TypeScript's control flow narrowing. By calling the type guard in a condition you can return `undefined` if `key` is no `keyof myObject`. 
`result` will be inferred as `'val1' | 'val2' | undefined` as you expected.

```
const myObject = {
  foo: 'val1',
  bar: 'val2'
} as const;
type Keys = keyof typeof myObject;

const getKey = () => (Math.random() < 0.5 ? "foo" : "bar") as string;
const key = getKey();

function isKeyOf<T extends Record<any, any>>(obj: T, key: PropertyKey): key is keyof T {
  return key in obj;
}

const result = isKeyOf(myObject, key) ? myObject[key] : undefined;
//    ^? const result: "val1" | "val2" | undefined
```

[TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBAtgTwPICMBWBTYsC8MDeAUDDAGYggBcMA5AG4CGANgIw0A0xMKDATtfWYAmGoQC+MBhBihIUANyEoCAA4YYAaQwJpeANbaQpGMrVH4ydFgWFCs6DADmGKFoQw8ACgCUHgHwwngCyDFAAFgB0vAxgACYgcD4wADwwAAwRAKwwAPwwAETkIPkw1Pk8vPm+UjDQvACWYI6K9rAG7njOrto+ioSkAK5g2PXgMPUQbkikyQAqMBgAHlAYcdIASlggvLHJMQjskmAIfn6eIOjUs4ft1AAKvCBqvMpu3tTt49Lt5vNEJLwXANeGAYJ9GjALmhFGJbK0YICIAMmLgvlNSJ5EKhMNgbtpfHksVZsABtdoAXVKMCGsQwpEaGFiigA9MySCQAHo5QhAA)

Answer (score 1):

You could always be explicit about it like so

```
function getResult() {
  const key = getKey(); // returns some random string key

  if (!(key in myObject))
    return undefined; 

  return myObject[key as keys];
}

const result = getResult();
```

And have that as a function